# Datadog allows me to create facets but it does not show any values for them

Tags: tags, metrics, datadog

I am using datadog to see my microservice metrics. When I go to APM tab I can see the spans I created and their corresponding tags are reaching the server correctly. The problem is that If I click in a tag "gear" to convert it to a facet, while the operation completes correctly I can not query for this value nor do I seee any value when I add it as a column to my metrics. Example below:

I can click that gear and convert "Headers-Received" to a string value, there is no error at all from DD, but I cannot query or see any value being registered. But I DO can see the values in each trace of a request reaching my server.

What is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but by default facets need to be created before logs are processed, which means it won't show old logs prior to the creation of facets.

Comment: Yes, but new logs still don't show the new facet values.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Datadog correctly parses only the log `attributes` to Measures - but not the log `tags`. Datadog allows the creation of Measures from `tags` now, but I assume it is for future support. In my case, converting the `tag` to an `attribute` made the Measure and related Metrics work just fine.